# Azure pipelines if statement not evaluating correctly

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a conditional where to goal is to run the following steps if

1. Reason is PullRequest and target branch is develop or master
2. Reason is IndividualCI and source branch is develop
3. Reason is manual and the source branch is NOT develop or master (I want users to be able to queue test builds on their feature branches but not on develop or master)

With that in mind I came up with this:

`- ${{ if or(and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), or(eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))), and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')), and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'), or(ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')))) }}:`

Or in more reader friendly format:

```
or(
  and(
    eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), 
    or(
        eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), 
        eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
    )
  ), 
  and(
    eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'), 
    eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')
  ), 
  and(
    eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'), 
    or(
        ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'),
        ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
    )
  )
)
```

This appears to work just fine in the manual build case and in the IndividualCI case, but when I open a PR it just checks out and does nothing. Im sure Im just missing something obvious.  Thanks all!

**EDIT**

Should note that I do have the branch policy set up. When the job runs the parameters appear to be populated and `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` does indeed have a value.

[image: Pipeline variables are set]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what was happening. Apparently `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` is a run time variable and thus not available in templates. As conditions are evaluated *before* run time variables are populated, it was always null upon evaluation. What I had to do is make a separate job just to set the variable, output that variable so then I could use it in conditions in the "real" job. Example:

```
variables:
  ..
  prTargetBranch: ''

jobs:
- job: setupVariables
  displayName: 'Setup variables for pipeline'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - powershell: 'Write-Host “##vso[task.setvariable variable=prTargetBranch;isoutput=true]$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)”'
    name: setupVariable
- job: build
  dependsOn: setupVariables
  displayName: 'Build'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  variables:
    prTargetBranch: $[ dependencies.setupVariables.outputs['setupVariable.prTargetBranch'] ]
  condition: or(and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), or(eq(variables['prTargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(variables['prTargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))), and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')), and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'), or(ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))))
  steps:
  ..
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that your PR is without build validation resulting in the "variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch']" is empty.

This variable is initialized only if the build ran because of a [Git PR affected by a branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation). This variable is only available in a YAML pipeline if the PR is affected by a branch policy.

You could also try to use other variables to check if the problem is related to this variable.

For more information, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: I do have the branch policy set up. It does run a build, it just only does the checkout step and skips everything else.  According to the job preparation parameters in the build info System.PullRequest.TargetBranch is indeed being set (I updated main post with screenshot)